# Using FilterIterator with java enhanced loops

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

My class contains a list myObjects and my class then have a method which need to return an filtered view of the content of this list.

For this I use the FilterIterator<> from org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.FilterIterator

Then I can create a filter iterator, which gives the caller exactly the objects which fulfill my predicate.

That works well, but there is one problem. Working with Iterable really to much boilerplate code, because javas enhanced for loops don't work with iterators.

So is there any canonical solution to this problem?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/IteratorIterable.html, or use Java 8, or use Guava.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that class. I am using Java 8, but I don't see how that will help me here.

Comment: Java 8 introduces lambdas, and the new Stream API, which is the most important change of the release, allowing precisely to perform map/filter/reduce operations on collections. `list.stream().filter(o -> isAcceptedByFilter(o)).collect(toList());` for example, creates a new list from a list and a predicate. There have been dozens of tutorials and blog posts about that. Google it.

Comment: Seems interesting, but that last call to toList() does not compile.

Comment: It's a static method of Collectors. Typically statically imported.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 has it’s own concept processing items using operations like filtering, mapping, reducing and collecting. With the new `Stream` API you can solve the task of performing an action on a filtered collection like this:

```
List<String> source=Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
source.stream().filter(s->s.startsWith("ba"))
      .forEach(element->System.out.println(element));
```

The Java 8 API has its own `Predicate` interface, but there is the neat feature of method references which makes it easy to translate these single method interfaces:

```
Predicate<String> pred=…;// org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate

source.stream().filter(pred::evaluate)
      .forEach( /* your action */);
```

Here, the method reference `pred::evaluate` at a place, where a [`java.util.function.Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) is expected, will create such a java util `Predicate` whose `test` method will delegate to the `evaluate` method of the existing apache commons `Predicate` instance.

---

You can even use a for-each loop for an existing iterator using a little trick:

```
Iterator<String> iterator= …

for(String s: (Iterable<String>) ()->iterator) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This uses a lambda expression telling Java that you want an `Iterable` whose `iterator()` method will return your existing iterator instance. Of course, you can iterate only once over an iterator, so that `Iterable` is a throw-away instance.

Comment: The Iterator-as-Iterable "trick" makes me deeply uncomfortable, so here's an alternative suggestion: the new `forEachRemaining` method on `Iterator`.  Your last example could be rewritten as `iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: it was just an addendum addressing the part of the question about using the for-each loop (external iteration). If you are willing to use internal iteration, you can use the `Stream` API anyway. But the internal iteration methods don’t support conditional `break` nor early `return`.